# Tensorflow InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): flat indices does not index into param

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, sparse-matrix

I'm using tensorflow to build a recommendationg system using collaborative filtering algorithm.

Due to memory usage I have to use sparse matrices.

```
#Arbitrary number of items are rated by arbitrary number of users
ratings = tf.sparse_placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, None])
ratings = tf.sparse_reorder(ratings)
```

With my feed_dict,
`ratings.dense_shape == (45776, 60184)`

```
pred = tf.matmul(items_features, user_preferences, name='Prediction') + global_mean
```

I have hardcoded so `pred.shape == (45776, 60184)`

So how comes when I try to collect predictions to later calculate the cost

```
pred_values = tf.gather_nd(pred, ratings.indices)
```

I get error
    InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): flat indices[2714679, :] = [48375, 2227] does not index into param (shape: [45776,60184]).
?

Comment: It's hard to answer without looking at your code. In particular, it would help to know the declaration and shape of `result`.

Comment: Sorry, edited. In my code "result" was "pred"

Comment: It looks like the `ratings` tensor has more rows (48375) than the `pred` tensor (45776). So you can't use the indices in `ratings` to access values in `pred`.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I did mess up with dimensions. I fed indices in the opposite order than I thought, i.e., for shape `(60184,45776)` instead of needed `(45776,60184)`.

Having an error telling that my `flat indices[2714679, :]` are indexing `[48375, 2227]` - shape that does not appear - didn't help.